On Quotient of an Affine Variety
I am currently working on the notes on algebraic geometry by Andreas Gathmann.
Here's his exercise 2.6.4:

Let $X$ be an affine variety, and let $G$ be a finite group. Assume that $G$ acts on $X$, i.e. for every $g \in G$ we are given a morphism $g:X \rightarrow X$ (denoted by the same letter for simplicity of notation), such that  $(g\circ h)(P)=g(h(P))$ for all $g,h \in G$ and $P \in X$.

For part (i) I showed that the subalgebra $G$-invariant functions $A(X)^G$ is a $k$-algebra of finite type. Then I got stuck in part (ii).

By (i), there is an affine variety $Y$ with coordinate ring $A(X)^G$, together with a morphism $\pi : X \rightarrow Y$ determined by the inclusion $A(X)^G \subset A(X)$. Show that $Y$ can be considered as  the quotient of $X$ by $G$, denoted $X/G$, in the following sense:
-$\pi$ is surjective.
-If $P, Q \in X$ then $\pi(P)=\pi(Q)$ if and only if there is a $g \in G$ such that $g(P)=Q$.

My troubles mainly reside in the first point, to prove that the morphism is surjective. Seemingly a trivial statement, I was unable to go through (due to my lacking knowledge in commutative algebra). Here is my attempt:

Write $A(X)^G=A(Y)=k[y_1, \dots, y_m]/I(Y)$. The inlcusion $A(X)^G \subset A(X)$ induces a $k$-Alg homomorphism from $A(Y)$ to $A(X)$ mapping each $y_i$ to a polynomial $P_i$. Given a point $(k_1, \dots, k_m) \in Y$, want to show that there is solution for the set of $m$ equations $P_i(x_1, \dots, x_n)=k_i$. This is equivalent to showing that the ideal $(P_1-k_1, \dots, P_m-k_m)+I(X)$ in $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is not equal to $(1)$.

I also observed that each of the $P_i$'s and any element from $I(X)$ is invariant under the action of $G$.
From here I have no idea how to proceed. Any enlightenment is appreciated.

Let $J\subseteq A(X)^G$ be the vanishing ideal of your point $(k_1,\dots,k_m)$. You want to show that $JA(X)\ne A(X)$. Note that $G$ acts on $A(X)$ by $\phi^g(x)=\phi(gx)$. Suppose $1\in JA(X)$, so $1=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i\phi_i$ with $f_i\in J, \phi_i\in A(X)$. Consider the polynomial $P(T_1,\dots,T_n)=\prod_{g\in G}\sum_{i=1}^nT_i\phi_i^g$. If we let $G$ act on the coefficients of a polynomial in $A(X)[T_1,\dots,T_n]$, then $P$ is invariant under the action of $G$, so when we multiply out the product, all the coefficients in the polynomial are invariant under $G$, hence lie in $A(Y)$. But note that $f_i^g=f_i$ for all $i,g$, so $1=\prod_g\sum_{i=1}^nf_i\phi_i^g=P(f_1,\dots,f_n)$, so we have expressed $1$ as a $A(Y)$-linear combination of elements in $J$, so $1\in J$, a contradiction.
This is an instance of a more general concept: The extension $A(X)/A(Y)$ is integral (because every $\phi\in A(X)$ is a root of $\prod_g(T-\phi^g)\in A(Y)[T]$), and if the homomorphism of rings is integral, the associated morphism of affine varieties is surjective.
